# Laravel 5.4: Notification delay, only execute upon condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

It is a chat function, I would like to have the notification delay by 5 seconds, within (or after) these 5seconds the notification will only be sent if the specific message is being read during the time. I have researched for `delay()` or using `sleep()` in php lib but they can't seem to do the trick for the conditioning. Is it possible to do such thing?

Answer (score 0):

use https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications#queueing-notifications

```
class InvoicePaid extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    // ...
}
$when = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10);

$user->notify((new InvoicePaid($invoice))->delay($when));
```

You can check condition inside Notification